# Opscenter can not connect to the nodes

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

Our opscenter can not connect to the nodes, in the logs the next error appears:

2015-08-17 08:56:37+0200 [SNPaware_Cluster]  INFO: Nodes with agents that appear to be no longer running: 172.31.7.245, 172.31.7.244, 172.31.7.247, 172.31.7.246, 172.31.7.243
2015-08-17 08:56:37+0200 [SNPaware_Cluster]  INFO: Nodes with agents that appear to be no longer running: 172.31.7.245, 172.31.7.244, 172.31.7.247, 172.31.7.246, 172.31.7.243
2015-08-17 08:56:38+0200 []  INFO: Stopping factory

We have disabled the firewall in all our nodes and opscenter (in fact we have another cluster configured which is actually working). The datastasx agents (version 2.0.5) are running in all the nodes but opscenter gets a timeout, the Cassandra version we are using is 2.0.16

Have anyone a hint on this?

Comment: The INFO log messages you posted are typically harmless, but indicate there are agents reporting to opscenterd that opscenterd cannot match to any of the Cassandra nodes it knows about.  This can either be caused by old agents that are still running, or misconfiguration in some network environments (You can read more about this in our [documentation][1]).  Beyond that, what symptom leads you to believe OpsCenter cannot connect to your cluster?


  [1]: http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/examples/opscConfiguringForMultipleRegions_t.html

Comment: I have delete from all the nodes the datastax agents and delete also the Opscenter keyspace, so there is no old agents running. O but pscenter can connect to the cluster, but it can not get the metrics for each node like disk space, etc... We are using the default ports and all the firewall are disabled.

Comment: Look in /var/log/datastax-agent/agent.log on one of the nodes to see if there are any obvious errors about connecting to the opscenterd IP.  If you can put the entire log in a gist or somewhere else accessible that would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end this is what it works for me.

- Remove all the datastax agents in each node.
- Delete the opscenter keyspace from the cluster.
- Reinstall the datastax agents in each node.
- Add the cluster to the opscenter througth the webinterface.
- Run a repair on each node on the opscenter keyspace.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting what you tried.  This totally helped me get OpsCenter running on a node that (I didn't know ) once had an older version of it.